# WordPress on add-on domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, configuration, path

I have installed WordPress on an add-on on BlueHost. The addon domain is linked to a sub-folder of the main domain FTP, called `addondomain-folder`.

When I go to addondomain.com, the WP site displays ok.
The problem is with the `wp-admin` panel. The panel displays incorrectly, has broken links to all images and stylesheets and I can not access any area as I always get redirected to: `addondomain.com/addondomain-folder/wp-admin/...` instead of `addondomain.com/wp-admin/`

I have checked the `wp-options` table in the database and both `siteurl` and `home` are set to  `addondomain.com`

Any solutions to stop `wp-admin` thinking it is in a subfolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was a hidden `.htaccess` file which messed everything up.